# Open excel file in a temporary file

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have been using excel interop for a while now but decided to start using EPPLUS library instead for some reasons.
I like it but I would like to open the excel files the same way Excel Interop does: Open the file as a temporary file that does not really exist anywhere.
So far, EPPLUS must save the file somewhere so that I can open it using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

What I have tried so far is delete the file after I open it:

```
excelPack.SaveAs(new FileInfo(name));                                                          
File.SetAttributes(name, FileAttributes.ReadOnly); //Force the user to save file As                                        
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(name);                                                                         
File.Delete(name); //Crash here. File is in use
```

But as you can see, it crashed at last line because the file is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is quite simple. Simply set the file attributes to normal before deleting it. This will somehow tell windows that the file is no longer in use:

```
                excelPack.SaveAs(new FileInfo(name));                                                          
                File.SetAttributes(name, FileAttributes.ReadOnly); //Force the user to save file As                                        
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(name);
                File.SetAttributes(name, FileAttributes.Normal);                                                                     
                File.Delete(name);
```

The file will be deleted but it will still be open in Excel in Read Only. The user will be able to save it.

Comment: That's a very neat trick, but couldn't there be a race condition where the file is deleted before the process has had a chance to open it?

Comment: I really don't know. I tried with some light file (about 5 kb) and larger one (4 Mb) with Excel initialy closed and never had a problem, yet.